# Cant add product to cart after upgrade to magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, addtocart, magento-upgrade

I have upgraded my site to magento 2.4.0. After the upgrade, i am not able to add products to cart.
Can anyone please help , what is the issue?
Reference link,
http://discountedsunglasses.magento2e.com/women/sunglasses/aviator/sunoptic-sp100-sunglasses

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to add the given product to cart, it works. Please check attached screenshot for the same.
https://prnt.sc/k0gHUR9KXOo6